# OData8 aggregate multiple count on nested Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, odata

I am trying to find the best solution to get the count and sum of large relational db using AspNetCore EntityFramework and/or OData8.

I have the following Entity models

```
    public class Entity1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Entity2>? Entity2s { get; set; }
    }
    public class Entity2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Entity1Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Entity3>? Entity3s { get; set; }
    }
    public class Entity3
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Entity2Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Entity4>? Entity4s { get; set; }
    }
    public class Entity4
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Entity3Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Entity3 Entity3 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Entity5>? Entity5s { get; set; }
    }
    public class Entity5
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public int Entity4Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Entity4 Entity4 { get; set; }
    }
```

> Note: there are over 100 000 items of each type.
> Not all Entity1 necessarily have Entity2s

What I want to get at the end of the day is the counts of each rolled up to the root entity and the sum of the Value in Entity5

```
[
   { E1: "e1_1", E2_Cnts: 5622, E3_Cnts: 876, E4_Cnts: 3242, E5_Cnts: 12, E5_Sum:42343},
   { E1: "e1_2", E2_Cnts: 64, E3_Cnts: 978, E4_Cnts: 321, E5_Cnts: 0, E5_Sum:0},
   ...
]
```

I searched for OData related and know that aggregation on expand wasn't first supported but it seems that it is now.

---

Option 1 Using Odata8 query

```
https://dev.local:7123/odata/Entity1s?$expand=Entity2s($select=Name;$count=true;$expand=Entity3s($select=Name;$count=true;$expand=Entity4s($select=Name;$count=true;$expand=Entity5s($top=0;$count=true))))
```

I get expected result, but the result is huge and then I have to map to calculate the counts I require.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://dev.local:7123/odata/$metadata#Entity1s(Entity2s(Name,Entity3s(Name,Entity4s(Name,Entity5s()))))",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "e1_1",
            "Entity2s@odata.count": 15,
            "Entity2s": [
                {
                    "Name": "e2_1",
                    "Entity3s@odata.count": 18,
                    "Entity3s": [
                        {
                            "Name": "e3_1",
                            "Entity4s@odata.count": 12,
                            "Entity4s": [
                                {
                                    "Name": "e4_1",
                                    "Entity5s@odata.count": 8,
                                    "Entity5s": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "Name": "e4_2",
                                    "Entity5s@odata.count": 19,
                                    "Entity5s": []
                                },
                                ...
```

Option 2 Using OData8

```
https://dev.local:7123/odata/Entity5s?apply=groupby((Entity4/Entity3/Entity2/Entity1/Name),aggregate($count%20as%20Count))
```

I get a much smaller result but only the count of Entity5. Also this has a drawback that any Entity 1 which doesnt contain any Entity5's wont be listed.

```
[
    {
        "Entity4": {
            "Entity3": {
                "Entity2": {
                    "Entity1": {
                        "Name": "e1_1"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "Count": 22685
    },
    {
        "Entity4": {
            "Entity3": {
                "Entity2": {
                    "Entity1": {
                        "Name": "e1_2"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "Count": 14881
    },
    ...
```

---

Option 3 Using just LINQ in controller like

```
    var model = _context.Entity1s.Include(x=>x.Entity2s).ThenInclude(x=>x.Entity3s).ThenInclude(x=>x.Entity4s).ThenInclude(x=>x.Entity5s)
```

I can populate view with

```
   @model.Name @model.Entity2s.Count() @model.Entity2s.SelectMany(x=>Sum(x.Entity3s.Count())).....
```

But as can be expected this is also a huge query and takes quite a while.

Option2 seems to be the best performing if I could just know hjow to include additional aggregations

```
        "Entity4": {
            "Entity3": {
                "Entity2": {
                    "Entity1": {
                        "Name": "e1_1"
                    }**,"Count": 234**
                }**,"Count": 34**
            }**,"Count": 234**
        },
        "Count": 23456
        **,"Sum": 234**
    },
```

Or even better yet to populate the Entity1 Name in the root by. This query times out for Entity1Name, but successfully populates for Entity4/Name.

```
https://dev.local:7123/odata/Entity5s?apply=groupby((Entity4/Entity3/Entity2/Entity1/Name),aggregate($count%20as%20Count,(Entity4/Entity3/Entity2/Entity1/Name) with max as Entity1Name))
```

to get

```
        "Entity4": {
            "Entity3": {
                "Entity2": {
                    "Entity1": {
                        "Name": "e1_2"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "Count": 14881,
        "Entity1Name" : "e1_2"
    },
```

Is there perhaps a way to use select in the above query to only show the root items Count and Entity1Name?

I am using

1. "Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="8.2.0"
2. "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.18"

Comment: It is difficult to meet your needs with OData alone. It seems that there is no syntax suitable for filtering and summing properties in nested models. In fact, the most suitable for your needs is to use Linq query, but your data is too large, which will inevitably lead to slow query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Chen for the response.

At the end of the day I ended up with a Stored Procedure on the SQL DB. This reduced the query load significantly.

For those interested here is a quick snapshot on what I did

Create Procedure in SQL

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO 
ALTER PROCEDURE EntitySummary 
     @Tenant varchar(max) ='Default'
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    SELECT
        dbo.Entity1s.Name, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Entity2s.Id) AS Entity2s_Cnt, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Entity3s.Id) AS Entity3s_Cnt, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Entity4s.Id) AS Entity4s_Cnt, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Entity5s.Id) AS Entity5s_Cnt, 
        Sum(dbo.Entity5s.Value) AS Entity5s_Sum
FROM dbo.Entity1s LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.Entity2s ON dbo.Entity2s.Entity1Id = dbo.Entity1s.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Entity3s ON dbo.Entity3s.Entity2Id = dbo.Entity2s.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Entity4s ON dbo.Entity4s.Entity3Id = dbo.Entity3s.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Entity5s ON dbo.Entity5s.Entity4Id = dbo.Entity4s.Id 
WHERE dbo.Entity1s.Tenant =  @Tenant
GROUP BY dbo.Entity1s.Name
RETURN
END
GO
```

Create model with expected results

```
    public class EntitySummary
    {
        public string? Entity1Name { get; set; }
        public int? Entity2_Cnt { get; set; }
        public int? Entity3_Cnt { get; set; }
        public int? Entity4_Cnt { get; set; }
        public int? Entity5_Cnt { get; set; }
        public int? Entity5_Sum {  get; set; }
    }
```

Create Summary Repository

```
    public interface ISummaries
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<EntitySummary>> GetEntitySummary(string Tenant);
    }
    public class SummariesRepository : ISummaries
    {
        readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public SummariesRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<EntitySummary>> GetEntitySummary(string Tenant)
        {
            try
            {
                return await _context.Set<EntitySummary>()
                   .FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE dbo.EntitySummary {Tenant}")
                   .ToListAsync();

            }
            catch
            {

                return new List<EntitySummary>();
            }  
        }

    }
```

In DbContext Add KeyLess

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<EntitySummary>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasNoKey();
            });
```

Add startup service

```
            services.AddTransient<ISummaries, SummariesRepository>();
```

And call from Controller

```
    public class SummariesController : BaseController<SummariesController>
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private ISummaries _report;

        public SummariesController(ApplicationDbContext context, ISummaries report)
        {
            _context = context;
            _report = report;
        }
         
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var model = await _report.GetEntitySummary(_context.MyTenant);
            return View(model);
        }
 
    }
```

In conclusion I think this is probably the most performant solution. If anyone has any better suggestions or could even improve on this I would really appreciate it.